# How to ensure all records of a header are under the same fiscal year?

Tags: constraint, date, db2-midrange

Say I have the following schema:

```
BUDGET_YEAR_TARGET
    INTEGER ID

BUDGET_DATE_TARGET
    INTEGER ID
    INTEGER BUDGET_YEAR_TARGET_ID--Foreign key
    DATE DATE
```

How can I ensure that any records of `BUDGET_DATE_TARGET` that share a `BUDGET_YEAR_TARGET_ID` will have `DATE`s under the same Fiscal Year (with Oct 1 as new year day)?

For example, this would be valid:

```
ID BUDGET_YEAR_TARGET_ID DATE
1  1                     Jan 1, 2020
2  1                     Jul 1, 2020
3  2                     Jan 1, 2020
4  2                     Aug 1, 2020
5  3                     Nov 1, 2020
```

If I were to insert a new record with a `DATE` of Dec 1, 2020, I'd like it to succeed if the `BUDGET_YEAR_TARGET_ID` is 3 but fail if it is 1 or 2.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

A before insert trigger might be an option...

However, a "dates table" aka "calendar table" is much more flexible, regardless of the DBMS you are using.

Basically, it's a pre-generated table of dates from say 1900-01-01 to 2200-12-31.  In addition to various date columsn, it would contain various flag columns (weekday, weekend, holiday) and other helpful columns (Fiscal year, Quarter).

A bit of searching will turn up lots of articles about using them.

For Db2 for i specifically, if you have the Web Query product installed, IBM provides a routine (LOAD_DATE_CONVERSION_TABLE) to generate one (QWQCENT.DATE_CONV) for you.  See chapter 5 of the [Redbook - IBM DB2 Web Query for i](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg248379.html?Open)

For your case, you could define a unique key constraint on your dates table over (date, fiscal_year) and then use that as a FK constraint in your BUDGET_DATE_TARGET.

However, you may find you don't need BUDGET_DATE_TARGET or BUDGET_YEAR_TARGET at all once you've got the dates table.